# PCI Compliance for developers accessing a production database for support

Tags: databases, pci-dss

As a developer, when an Incident comes in and reaches Tier 3 support (The development team), how can the developers get access to query the Production Database, while remaining PCI Compliant? I'm admittedly a newbie when it comes to PCI Compliance. Is this just a case of Read-Only accounts? Is this a case of data masking? Is this a case of having a Production copy within Production so devs can't hit a "Live" db? What's the easiest, and compliant way for developers to be able to perform application incident support in production?

Answer (score 3):

DSS 6.4.2 *Separation of duties between development/test and production environments* is careful to note that it is not prohibiting developers from Production, just controlling them:

> The intent of this requirement is to separate development and test
> functions from production functions. For example, a developer may use
> an administrator-level account with elevated privileges in the
> development environment, and have a separate account with user-level
> access to the production environment.

So restricting privileges is a good start - read only access where possible, limited administrative rights enforced with something like sudo or PowerBroker as necessary.

Aside from restricting privileges, a standard way of dealing with this would be to use Incident and Change Control processes to document why any given developer was acting in Production at a given point of time, and to generate an audit log that can be used to evaluate what actions were taken in the time/place covered by a ticket.  Remember, at some level, you want to be able to walk the auditor through your controls.

If your workflow permits it, dual control can be a useful restraint upon developers, ensuring that a second pair of eyes is monitoring the activity.  That can be difficult to arrange; developers get called into Production emergencies because they're, well, emergencies, and not neatly scheduled.